# PowerShell Tools can't download files from cloud storage, but gsutil works

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-powershell

Managed to get the PowerShell cmdlets installed and have been trying to  download or list files in our bucket. I keep getting this message when I try any commands, [as shown in the documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-powershell/#/google-cloud-storage).

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

[image: Screenshot]

When I use `gsutil`, I can download files just fine.

Is there a setting I may have missed?

Comment: What is the value of your $bucket variable?

Comment: This error usually occurs when using a variable with no set value (not initialized). what is the value of the variable?

Answer (score -1):

what is you powershell version? Make sure you have latest powershell version 5.0 installed on your machine.

I was facing similar issue and could resolve by installing powershell 5.0.

I hope this helps.

Regards,
Praful

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Read-gcsobject to download a file